# exit tkinter gui python program when click pystray menu build with asyncio and fastapi

Tags: tkinter, python-asyncio, pystray

minimal code

```
import sys
import threading
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.responses import FileResponse
from tkinter import *

from fastapi.staticfiles import StaticFiles
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware
from pystray import MenuItem as item
import pystray
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import asyncio
import tkinter as tk
from asyncio import CancelledError
from contextlib import suppress
import random

app = FastAPI()
# Allow all origins
app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=["*"],  # You can replace this with specific origins if needed
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)

async def one_url(url):
    """One task."""
    sec = random.randint(1, 8)
    await asyncio.sleep(sec)
    return "url: {}\tsec: {}".format(url, sec)


async def do_urls():
    """Creating and starting 10 tasks."""
    tasks = [one_url(url) for url in range(10)]
    completed, pending = await asyncio.wait(tasks)
    results = [task.result() for task in completed]
    print("\n".join(results))
def _asyncio_thread(async_loop):
    async_loop.run_until_complete(do_urls())


def do_tasks(async_loop):
    """Button-Event-Handler starting the asyncio part."""
    threading.Thread(target=_asyncio_thread, args=(async_loop,)).start()

def start(lang, root=None, async_loop=None):
    global mainwindow, canvas

    # root.resizable(width=True, height=True)
    root.iconbitmap("assets/icon.ico")
    root.title('tkinter asyncio demo')
    Button(master=root, text="Asyncio Tasks", command=lambda: do_tasks(async_loop)).pack()


    root.update_idletasks()

async def wait():


    try:
        tasks = asyncio.all_tasks(loop)
        print(f'========{tasks}')
        for task in tasks:
            try:
                # await asyncio.sleep(3600)
                await task.cancel()
            except asyncio.exceptions.CancelledError:
                print("done")


    except RuntimeError as err:
        print('SIGINT or SIGTSTP raised')
        print("cleaning and exiting")
        sys.exit(1)


async def quit_window(icon, item):
    global loop, fastapi_thread, server

    print('shutdown icon')
    icon.stop()

    print('shutdown server')
    server.should_exit = True
    server.force_exit = True
    await server.shutdown()

    print(f'0:{asyncio.all_tasks(loop)}')
    try:
        if loop.is_running():
            loop.call_soon_threadsafe(loop.stop)
            tasks = asyncio.all_tasks(loop)
            print(tasks, '========')
            for task in tasks:
                try:
                    task.cancel()
                    with suppress(CancelledError):
                        await loop.run_until_complete(task)
                except asyncio.exceptions.CancelledError:
                    print("done")
    except RuntimeError as err:
        print('SIGINT or SIGTSTP raised')
        print("cleaning and exiting")
        sys.exit(1)

    print('shutdown root')
    root.destroy()

    await asyncio.run(wait())

    print('close loop')

    print(f'1:{asyncio.all_tasks(loop)}')
    loop.stop()

def show_window(icon, item):
    icon.stop()
    root.after(0, root.deiconify)


def withdraw_window():
    root.withdraw()
    image = Image.open("assets/icon.ico")
    menu = (item("Quit", quit_window), item("Show", show_window))
    icon = pystray.Icon("name", image, "title", menu)
    # icon.run_detached()
    icon.run()

def start_fastapi_server(loop):
    import uvicorn
    global server
    config = uvicorn.Config(app, loop=loop, host="0.0.0.0", port=8000)
    server = uvicorn.Server(config)
    try:
        loop.run_until_complete(server.serve())
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Received Ctrl+C. Stopping gracefully...")
        # Cancel all running tasks
        for task in asyncio.Task.all_tasks():
            task.cancel()
        # Optionally: Close any open resources (sockets, files, etc.)
        # Cleanup code here
    finally:
        loop.close()




def start_tkinter_app(async_loop):
    global root, settings, db, canvas, locale
    root = tk.Tk()

    locale = 'en'
    start(locale, root, async_loop)

    root.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', withdraw_window)


    root.mainloop()




if __name__ == "__main__":
    global loop,fastapi_thread
    loop=None
    if sys.platform == 'win32':
        asyncio.get_event_loop().close()
        # On Windows, the default event loop is SelectorEventLoop, which does
        # not support subprocesses. ProactorEventLoop should be used instead.
        # Source: https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-subprocess.html
        loop = asyncio.ProactorEventLoop()
        asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    else:
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    # Start FastAPI server in a separate thread
    fastapi_thread = threading.Thread(target=start_fastapi_server,args=(
            loop,)).start()


    start_tkinter_app(loop)
    # loop.run_forever()
    # loop.close()
    fastapi_thread.join()
    loop.close()
```

this demo runs will start a thread for fastapi server to host static files,
and a tkinter gui app for user management.
we use pystray to hide gui to system tray.

when I click quit menu,it should stop all the thread and loop,destroy tk root,kill the backend python, but as you can see , I tried many choices,it all failed.

Comment: Try using `icon.run()` instead of `icon.run_detached()`.

Comment: no.that is not the problem. and if you run the code,it failed at the same issue